# Why sql server send varbinary big data to application so slow?

Tags: sql-server, varbinary

I have 2 server :

1. Database Server
2. Application Server

and client pc.

On Database server using ms sql server i save data file in varbinary(max).

On Application server using c# linq to sql i query  select top 1 file from database server. It takes too long to receive data from server database. it takes 3 minutes for 1 MB row size.

So i try to open management studio from my PC and execute this query :

```
Select Top 1 * from DataFile
```

it takes 2 minutes to show data in my management studio.

i think may be there is problem on database server performance, so i open management stdio on database server, i execute the same script. Zapp only 1 second to show the data.

I think there is a problem with connection, so i try upload and download a file (2mb) from database server. and Zapp only 3 seconds.

Why this happen? how to solve this problem? or may be if there are more information you need just tell me, i will try to provide.

Comment: Can you disable your firewall or antivirus on all machines and try again?

Comment: i deactivated all firewall and antivirus

Comment: Can you run SQL Profiler and see what is running when you execute the query using the application?